# PyQt listview with html rich text delegate moves text bit out of place(pic and code included)

Tags: qt, listview, delegates, pyqt, pyside

[image: gif showing with delegate and without]

Got a listview where items need to make use of bold text, so a html delegate is the way to go. I looked around and found several solutions and out of them I made this code, but it has the issue that you can see in the gif, which shows the results with the use of the delegate and without.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class HTMLDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HTMLDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.doc = QTextDocument(self)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()

        options = QStyleOptionViewItemV4(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)

        self.doc.setHtml(options.text)
        options.text = ""

        style = QApplication.style() if options.widget is None \
            else options.widget.style()
        style.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

        ctx = QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()

        if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                                 QPalette.Active, QPalette.HighlightedText))

        textRect = style.subElementRect(QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options)
        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

        painter.restore()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    main_list = QListView()
    main_list.setItemDelegate(HTMLDelegate())
    main_list.setModel(QStringListModel(data))
    main_list.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here are [PyQt5](http://pastebin.com/mNb5hsFg) and [PySide](http://pastebin.com/Ndf4YFp9a) versions

I dont use sizeHint, since through my testing it didnt feel like it was affecting this behavior.
Some attribute is positioning the text wrongly, I have been able to partly counter it with:

`self.doc.setDocumentMargin(0)`

the default margin is 4, and then move the whole item bit to the right

```
rect = options.rect
options.rect = QRect(rect.x()+3, rect.y(), rect.width(), rect.height())
```

But I dont think it addresses the cause of this issue, it just masks it and it becomes a problem again once you try add [icons for example](http://pastebin.com/MDdjJLEy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one is now the one I use

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class HTMLDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.doc = QTextDocument(self)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()

        options = QStyleOptionViewItem(option)

        self.initStyleOption(options, index)
        self.doc.setHtml(options.text)
        options.text = ""

        style = QApplication.style() if options.widget is None \
            else options.widget.style()
        style.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

        ctx = QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()

        print(QStyle.State_Selected)

        if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                QPalette.Active, QPalette.HighlightedText))
        else:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                QPalette.Active, QPalette.Text))

        textRect = style.subElementRect(
            QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options)

        if index.column() != 0:
            textRect.adjust(5, 0, 0, 0)

        thefuckyourshitup_constant = 4
        margin = (option.rect.height() - options.fontMetrics.height()) // 2
        margin = margin - thefuckyourshitup_constant
        textRect.setTop(textRect.top() + margin)

        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
        self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

        painter.restore()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return QSize(self.doc.idealWidth(), self.doc.size().height())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    main_list = QListView()
    main_list.setItemDelegate(HTMLDelegate())
    main_list.setModel(QStringListModel(data))
    main_list.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Well after some more digging and trying, adjusting the text rectangle seems to give the feel that everything is allright and seems to behave consistently in various DEs

```
    textRect.adjust(-1, -4, 0, 0)
```

I am not sure if its a bug, but one would expect that `SE_ItemViewItemText` should have give the correct position on its own

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but since I ran across this with a similar problem I thought  I'd address some problems with your code.  Mostly, it is the self.doc member.  It is not going to work as you had hoped.  The sizeHint() method is called (multiple times) before paint() is called (multiple times) and will be getting an empty document (which is why you "didnt feel like it was affecting this behavior".

You might think well, just initialize the document in sizeHint() vs paint() then, but that would also be wrong.  There is just one delegate and document for your list, so the document would always be based on the last one sized or painted, so having self.doc as a member only saves you the document construction which is probably not worth it considering the confusion it causes.